# Python issue:Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

I'm trying to install MySql interface for python, but I got an error (mentioned below). And I know the solution: install Microsoft Visual C++. Is there any alternative solution apart from installing Microsoft Visual C++? I mean this has really hurt me; why should I install Microsoft Visual C++ just because to build this single package it's a useless and time-wasting approach from the developer's perspective. Is there any alternative solution for this issue?

```
MySQL-python-1.2.3c1>setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I'm using Python 2.6 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You will need MSVC compiler or mingw32 to compile that, and also need MySQL Header files.

I've compiled once for MySQL1.2.3c1 for Python2.6, you could find it [here](http://soemin.googlecode.com/files/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.win32-py2.6.exe).

Comment: I'd upvote you twice if I could. This would be great to have on the Python-MySQL site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Comment: for Py 2.7 on Win32, use this: http://soemin.googlecode.com/files/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.win32-py2.7.exe

Comment: Also run into this problem trying to build Mercurial and install it into Python that is embedded in the Bitnami Trac Stack.

Comment: Managed to install from http://www.codegood.com/archives/129 (Python 2.7 32 and 64), the above install links gave me errors

Answer (score 14):

I realize this question is over a year old. However, YOU's executables don't work for Win64 machines. I've found Christopher Gohlke's Python libraries extremely helpful: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.

For MySQL-python on Win64 and Py27: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/49ej5jcn/MySQL-python-1.2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  it worked for me on windows 7 64 bit intel core i3. Thanks Logan.

Comment: Grt! This works for windows 8.1 64 bit with python 2.7.8

Answer (score 9):

You can also try this:
http://blog.eddsn.com/2010/05/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

Comment: Does not work for me with python 2.7

Answer (score 8):

Installation of `mysql-python` is confusing. It wasted my hours to deal with errors. Finally, I encounter [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). It refers a compiled file. Try it.

Comment: this is great! Thank you for saving me many hours of pain.

Comment: ^^ agreed i was at 2 hours and counting.. this was a life saver

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether it helps you, but check out [**this forum thread**](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/751115), it could be a version issue.

> There are important differences between the several versions of VC++.
>   The most important discrepancy is the runtime library version. Each
>   version of Visual Studio uses its own msvcrt dll. The command line
>   options, deprecated functions, project file formats and other things are
>   also slightly different.

Comment: I'm sure your alot is glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach for me was to go here http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/ and get the executable.

This made it easy.