# Installing a python wrapper for a c++ library

Tags: c++, python, wrapper

I am trying to install the python wrapper for the ANN (approx near neighbors) c++ library: link is http://www.scipy.org/scipy/scikits/wiki/AnnWrapper .  I am on Windows 7 32-bit.

Unfortunately the documentation is a bit terse and I am a newbie to programming in general, so I cannot decipher the instructions found within.  I have not built a C++ library before and am not even sure how to get that far.  Can anyone please guide?

Thanks!

gene

Comment: You should first try to follow the installation guide on the page step by step. If you have problem with a particular step, like WTF is easy_install and how to get it work on WIN 7?, post here and stackoverflow will answer ;)

Comment: Fair enough. I downloaded James Hetland's wrapper at the bottom of the page and put it in the directory I have my other external Python modules in.  I ran the setup.py file but I still can not import the scikits.ann package successfully.  It doesn't recognize it.  Has anyone actually successfully installed this in windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors warnings during installation? Do you have multiple Python installations on the system?

Comment: No I don't think so.  Does anyone have experience with Rob Hetland's wrapper?  I think that one must be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

To install Rob Hetland's wrapper you'll need to execute the following command (or one very similar depending on the C compiler installed on your system) in the directory that you've extracted the archive into:

`python setup.py build install`

or

`python setup.py build install --compiler=mingw32`

If you don't have a C compiler, or are getting errors, try looking here:

[potential issue + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879014/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-error-when-trying-to-install-qrcode-0-2-1)

[potential issue + answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272786/python-issueunable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

[Ming32 - gcc compatible compiler for Windows](http://www.mingw.org/)

[Using Microsoft Visual Studio Express](http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/)