# "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error when trying to install qrcode-0.2.1

Tags: python, installation, qr-code

Please help me to solve this error

```
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pyqrcode\encoder>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing qrcode.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to qrcode.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to qrcode.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
package init file 'qrcode\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
writing manifest file 'qrcode.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'qrcode.Encoder' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Thanks,

manu

Comment: Using code section makes it better for others to read :)

Comment: The top answer here helped me with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Answer (score 17):

Distutils does not play well with MS Compiler tool chain.

This file is required to setup the environment which will help distutils to use MS compiler tool chains.

There are quite a few ways in which this has been made to work.

Please look at the following post which may help you.

- [Compile Python 2.7 Packages With Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://web.archive.org/web/20101221084639/http://nukeit.org/compile-python-2-7-packages-with-visual-studio-2010-express/)<sup>*†*</sup>

*<sup>†</sup> The link goes to archive.org, since the [original page](http://nukeit.org/compile-python-2-7-packages-with-visual-studio-2010-express/) went away.*

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this more than once. I've been having issues with compiling the neo4j.py package on Windows and this is the only suggestion that has helped. I've tried MinGW after running into the vcvarsall.bat issue but went back to Visual Studio after running into some compiler flag issues.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kugel: Blog seems to be down at the moment. Please see some details that are as appropriate. http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/

Comment: Finally an answer that doesn't involve using Mingw32. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW link is dead even on archive.org

Answer (score 4):

This was [a known bug](http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/issues/detail?id=104), and should not be an issue anymore.

If using MinGW, try:

```
setup.py install build ––compiler=mingw32
```

Comment: Below error occur
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Iencoder/./src/ -IC:\Python26\i     
                                                         
nclude -IC:\Python26\PC -c encoder/Encoder.c -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\enc


oder\encoder.o

gcc: encoder/Encoder.c: No such file or directory


gcc: no input files


error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: c: No such file or directory gcc: no input files error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1