# CRC16 in Python

Tags: python, perl, crc, crc16

How do I calculate CRC16 in Python?

In Perl I would write something like:

```
use Digest::CRC "crc16";
$result = crc16($str);
```

How do I do same thing in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a library for calculating CRC16 here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/crc16/0.1.0

Comment: i get this error error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat when running the setup script.. any ideas?

Comment: try look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272786/python-issueunable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat