# C CRC Calculation method rewritten in Python seems wrong

Tags: python, c, crc, crc16

Note: [CRC16 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292290/crc16-in-python) topic does  not solve my problem. Deploying python package into server is restricted. Also my need is not a library to implement, I already wrote a function for this. My need is just correcting my function.

I need to implement a CRC calculator into our project for checking incoming data consistency. There is an example **C snippet** in device documents. I try to rewrite it in **Python** but I can't get right results in no way. For instance:

This is the data to be CRC calculated: `1f120f0c110e2103cc041f8ab002ea38040015440000000000000000083f`

The calculated CRC value should be `9911`.

The original C snippet:

```
static const U16 crctab16 [] =
{
0X0000, 0X1189, 0X2312, 0X329B, 0X4624, 0X57AD, 0X6536, 0X74BF,
0X8C48, 0X9DC1, 0XAF5A, 0XBED3, 0XCA6C, 0XDBE5, 0XE97E, 0XF8F7,
0X1081, 0X0108, 0X3393, 0X221A, 0X56A5, 0X472C, 0X75B7, 0X643E,
0X9CC9, 0X8D40, 0XBFDB, 0XAE52, 0XDAED, 0XCB64, 0XF9FF, 0XE876,
0X2102, 0X308B, 0X0210, 0X1399, 0X6726, 0X76AF, 0X4434, 0X55BD,
0XAD4A, 0XBCC3, 0X8E58, 0X9FD1, 0XEB6E, 0XFAE7, 0XC87C, 0XD9F5,
0X3183, 0X200A, 0X1291, 0X0318, 0X77A7, 0X662E, 0X54B5, 0X453C,
0XBDCB, 0XAC42, 0X9ED9, 0X8F50, 0XFBEF, 0XEA66, 0XD8FD, 0XC974,
0X4204, 0X538D, 0X6116, 0X709F, 0X0420, 0X15A9, 0X2732, 0X36BB,
0XCE4C, 0XDFC5, 0XED5E, 0XFCD7, 0X8868, 0X99E1, 0XAB7A, 0XBAF3,
0X5285, 0X430C, 0X7197, 0X601E, 0X14A1, 0X0528, 0X37B3, 0X263A,
0XDECD, 0XCF44, 0XFDDF, 0XEC56, 0X98E9, 0X8960, 0XBBFB, 0XAA72,
0X6306, 0X728F, 0X4014, 0X519D, 0X2522, 0X34AB, 0X0630, 0X17B9,
0XEF4E, 0XFEC7, 0XCC5C, 0XDDD5, 0XA96A, 0XB8E3, 0X8A78, 0X9BF1,
0X7387, 0X620E, 0X5095, 0X411C, 0X35A3, 0X242A, 0X16B1, 0X0738,
0XFFCF, 0XEE46, 0XDCDD, 0XCD54, 0XB9EB, 0XA862, 0X9AF9, 0X8B70,
0X8408, 0X9581, 0XA71A, 0XB693, 0XC22C, 0XD3A5, 0XE13E, 0XF0B7,
0X0840, 0X19C9, 0X2B52, 0X3ADB, 0X4E64, 0X5FED, 0X6D76, 0X7CFF,
0X9489, 0X8500, 0XB79B, 0XA612, 0XD2AD, 0XC324, 0XF1BF, 0XE036,
0X18C1, 0X0948, 0X3BD3, 0X2A5A, 0X5EE5, 0X4F6C, 0X7DF7, 0X6C7E,
0XA50A, 0XB483, 0X8618, 0X9791, 0XE32E, 0XF2A7, 0XC03C, 0XD1B5,
0X2942, 0X38CB, 0X0A50, 0X1BD9, 0X6F66, 0X7EEF, 0X4C74, 0X5DFD,
0XB58B, 0XA402, 0X9699, 0X8710, 0XF3AF, 0XE226, 0XD0BD, 0XC134,
0X39C3, 0X284A, 0X1AD1, 0X0B58, 0X7FE7, 0X6E6E, 0X5CF5, 0X4D7C,
0XC60C, 0XD785, 0XE51E, 0XF497, 0X8028, 0X91A1, 0XA33A, 0XB2B3,
0X4A44, 0X5BCD, 0X6956, 0X78DF, 0X0C60, 0X1DE9, 0X2F72, 0X3EFB,
0XD68D, 0XC704, 0XF59F, 0XE416, 0X90A9, 0X8120, 0XB3BB, 0XA232,
0X5AC5, 0X4B4C, 0X79D7, 0X685E, 0X1CE1, 0X0D68, 0X3FF3, 0X2E7A,
0XE70E, 0XF687, 0XC41C, 0XD595, 0XA12A, 0XB0A3, 0X8238, 0X93B1,
0X6B46, 0X7ACF, 0X4854, 0X59DD, 0X2D62, 0X3CEB, 0X0E70, 0X1FF9,
0XF78F, 0XE606, 0XD49D, 0XC514, 0XB1AB, 0XA022, 0X92B9, 0X8330,
0X7BC7, 0X6A4E, 0X58D5, 0X495C, 0X3DE3, 0X2C6A, 0X1EF1, 0X0F78,
};



// calculate 16 bits CRC of the given length data.

U16 GetCrc16(const U8* pData, int nLength)
{
    U16 fcs = 0xffff; // Initialize
    while(nLength>0)
    {
        fcs = (fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *pData) & 0xff];
        nLength--;
        pData++;
    }
    return ~fcs; // Negate
}

// Check whether the 16 bits CRC of the given length data is right.
BOOL IsCrc16Good(const U8* pData, int nLength)
{
    U16 fcs = 0xffff;
    // Initialize
    while(nLength>0)
    {
        fcs = (fcs >> 8) ^ crctab16[(fcs ^ *pData) & 0xff];
        nLength--;
        pData++;
    }
    return (fcs == 0xf0b8); // 0xf0b8 is CRC-ITU 的"Magic Value"
}
```

But the rewriten code in Python below is computing the crc value as `-26351`

```
CRC16_TABLE = [
    0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
    0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
    0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
    0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
    0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
    0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
    0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
    0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
    0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
    0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
    0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
    0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
    0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
    0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
    0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
    0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
    0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
    0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
    0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
    0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
    0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
    0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
    0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
    0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
    0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
    0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
    0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
    0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
    0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
    0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
    0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
    0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78,
]

def check(data):
    _str = ''
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(data) / 2):
        _str = _str + data[2 * i:2 * i + 2] + ','
    return _str[0:-1]

def compute(data):
    crc = 0xffff
    for byte in check(data).split(","):
        crc = ((crc >> 8) ^ CRC16_TABLE[(crc ^ (int(byte, 16) & 0xff)) & 0xff])
    return ~crc
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: well, start by writting the value in unsigned hex, no?

Comment: There are multiple CRC calculators, make sure you're using the same algorithm for both your own code and the reference.

Comment: Can you just use the built-in `binascii.crc32()` function?

Comment: @MarkRansom that's not really relevant, OP is comparing the C code and the Python code which is a port from the C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-26351` is a (signed) integer written in decimal notation, while `9911` is in hexadecimal notation. Your function is actually correct:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>h', -26351)
'\x99\x11'
```

Comment: Does `'>h'` shouldn't be the `'>i'` ?

Some values are causing `'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767` like `-62762`

Comment: It's actually *not* correct.  The return value should be in the range of an unsigned 16-bit integer, i.e. in the range 0 ... (2**16 - 1) inclusive.  It's mostly correct, except for the complement operation in the `return` statement.  My solution fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `return` statement in `compute`.  You want this to be a 16-bit value.  You could mask the result, or use the following:

```
return 0xffff - crc
```

And, as has been noted, format the result as a hex number if you want it to appear as `9911`.  The decimal value is `39185`.

Comment: I'm feeling a little dumb for asking, but could you elaborate on what you mean by "avoid any word size dependencies [...]" and why you don't need to mask the value? I don't understand what `0xffff - crc` would give you...

Comment: The pre-complemented crc value is in the range of a 16-bit unsigned integer.  The goal is to complement it and return the low-order 16 bits.  Subtracting it from `0xffff` clearly does this.  You could also use `((~crc) & 0xffff)`, which requires two operations rather than just one but should produce the same result.  I think my concern about this was invalid.  I'll update the comment in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

here is the python plugin to crc calculation.

it was written with c programming language

https://github.com/giraysam/crc-for-python.

in python script.

```
import crc

print crc.getcrc16("1f120f0c110e2103cc041f8ab002ea38040015440000000000000000083f") // output "9911"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written the following code for calculating crc8:

```
acklist = [] # a list of your byte string data
x = 0xff
    crc = 0
    for i in range(len(acklist)):
        crc += int(acklist[i], 16) & x

print(crc)

crc = ~crc
crc += 1

crc1 = crc >> 8 & x
crc2 = crc & x
```