# If Python is interpreted, why do you need a compiler for setup.py

Tags: python, installation

There's a lot about python that I just don't understand, so forgive me if this is an overly basic question.

I run python 2.7 on windows and when installing a package using setuptools' setup.py, I often run in to the following error: `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat` which is an issue discussed all over the place, including here:  [Python issue:Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272786/python-issueunable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) and here: http://blog.eddsn.com/2010/05/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

My question is, if python is an interpreted language, why do you even need a compiler to install a package?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python is interpreted, but many libraries use compiled C extensions.  The error you are seeing occurs when the auto-installer is unable to compile the C extensions for a given package.

Comment: C extensions are often used for performance reasons.  If you know C yourself it is sometimes worth writing custom extensions for performance intensive code, especially that found inside an inner loop.  If you want to stay mostly with python but get some of the benefits of C, look at Cython.

Comment: So not all packages require a compiler then (ie. a package that doesn't make use of C extensions wouldn't need a compiler), right?