# How to install python-Levenshtein windows

Tags: python, windows-8, levenshtein-distance

I saw there was a similar question asked about installing levenshtein in python, but was instructed to start my own by another user, so here it goes.

I am runnings windows 8 64bit. When I try to install Levenshtein I get the following error.

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\python-Levenshtein-0.10.2>python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\requires.txt
writing python_Levenshtein.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing namespace_packages to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt

writing top-level names to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to python_Levenshtein.egg-info\entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in distribu
tion
warning: no previously-included files matching '.project' found anywhere in dist
ribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.pydevproject' found anywhere in
 distribution
writing manifest file 'python_Levenshtein.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
building 'Levenshtein' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I was instructed to install setup-tools, which I've done. As well as

> download vcsetup.exe from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6506 run it
>
> after it finishes open your command.exe
>
> type :easy_install python-Levenshtein (this assumes you have setuptools already)

However, when I type "easy_install" I get the following message. I am also confused about the wording. Should I be directing to to setup.py?

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\python-Levenshtein-0.10.2>easy_install python-Leve
nshtein
'easy_install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272786/python-issueunable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat?rq=1), or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667069/cannot-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-running-a-python-script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with `easy_install` happens because your python scripts folder is not in PATH. Just add the following to the PATH:

```
 C:\Python27\Scripts
```

As about your initial problem, you should look to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat).