# Python 3.4 Installing psutil on Windows 7 x64

Tags: python, psutil

I'm trying to install from source psutil 2.1.0 for Python 3.4. My OS is Windows 7 x64. I receive the error:

```
c:\Python34\psutil-2.1.0>python setup.py install --verbose
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing top-level names to psutil.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing psutil.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to psutil.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'psutil.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs
build'
writing manifest file 'psutil.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.4
creating build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\psutil
running build_ext
building '_psutil_windows' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Can you help me please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vcvarsall.bat` looks like a dependency for Microsoft Visual Studio.

See: [Python issue:Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272786/python-issueunable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat?rq=1)

You could try to install it manually. Get the amd64 py3.4 build from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psutil

And install it. If that fails as well, use 7-Zip to open the .exe and unpack the contained folder to your site-packages.

Comment: Problem resolved. First of all I unistalled the x64 python and I installed Python x32 version. After that I installed psutil 2.1.0 x32 from your link, everything works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try my experience. I hope it will be helpful
I have Ptython 3.4 installed. I was trying to install 'paramiko' modul and I've recieved an error message (vcvarsall.bat)

So after that I did folowing:
1. **install MinGW** (refer to page- http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/appendix.html)
2. **install pycrypto2.6.1** (I've found it here - https://github.com/axper/python3-pycrypto-windows-installer)
      *for others python version please refer this page* -- www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto
3. **check**