# Error installing flask-mysql python module

Tags: python, flask, flask-mysql

I'm trying to install the flask-mysql module and am running into an error. It looks like a problem with vcvarsall.bat, but I'm not really sure what that hints at.

Any ideas from someone more experienced than myself?

```
C:\eb-virt\bucketlist>pip install flask-mysql

Collecting flask-mysql
  Using cached Flask_MySQL-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MySQL-python (from flask-mysql)
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): itsdangerous>=0.21 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): click>=2.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Werkzeug>=0.7 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Flask->flask-mysql)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask->flask-mysql)
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, flask-mysql
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\tonype~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-3xn7it\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\tonype~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-vtdlrx-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\tonype~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-3xn7it\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\tonype~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-vtdlrx-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\tonype~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-3xn7it\MySQL-python\
```

Comment: It requires some native code compilation. you need a version of visual c++ 2008 ([aka VS 9.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_and_64-bit_versions)), which is the same version that python 2.7 itself is compiled with. There is a microsoft compiler specifically for python 2.7 modules [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=44266). I never tried it though.

Comment: also make sure, you install proper mysql (x86 vs x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using these [binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) for [windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) distributions. Flask-mysql uses mysql-python which has [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440230/install-mysql-python-windows) when trying to install on windows. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8047236/4675937).

Comment: Thank you! The last link in your answer solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Often this type of error occurred when you have installed python **32bit** and mysql **64bit** or vice versa. Try out same installations. I have experienced this error with **postgresSql** and python on this command **pip install psycopg2**
May be this will solve you issue.